# RoR : serialized data in built response object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, serialization, activerecord, controller

I'm building a Rails API, and I have this controller method that responds with a custom object:

```
class V1::AppInitController < ApplicationController
  def init
    json_response({
      user: UserSerializer.new(current_user, {}).as_json,
      categories: ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer.new(Category.all, each_serializer: CategorySerializer).as_json,
      last_seen_products: current_user.last_seen_products
    })
  end
end
```

Since I'm building a custom object here, I have to manually call the serializers if I want them to be applied.
Is it possible to configure my controllers so that serializers are applied automatically?

What I want in the end is being able to write my method this way, being automatically serialized:

```
class V1::AppInitController < ApplicationController
  def init
    json_response({
      user: current_user,
      categories: Category.all,
      last_seen_products: current_user.last_seen_products
    })
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible. However, you can make a new serializer, pass the objects as instance_options and call the individual serializers in this serializer. So, from the controller, you only use this new serializer.

Answer (score 0):

modify your init method as below and try it.

```
class V1::AppInitController < ApplicationController
 def init
  json_response({
    user: UserSerializer(current_user),
    categories: CategorySerializer(Category.all),
    last_seen_products: current_user.last_seen_products
  })
 end
end
```

I hope it's work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm having it working pretty much like this (except for the category array, I'm using ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer), but I'm trying to apply the serializers without having to explicitly call them

Comment: In AMS while you use `render :json` and if you pass some ApplicationRecord object it will go to find serializer for that object by default. but in your case, you are trying to passing HASH in `render :json` so that why it does not convert your hash to the serializer. other wise how application know where to use serializer record and when to use an actual record